# What does "stand submitted upon" mean in a law document?

Tags: meaning

I am reading a document issued by a court, but I fail to get the meaning of "stand submitted upon" in the following sentence, especially the word "stand".

> The Order will stand submitted upon the filing of the response to the Order to Show Cause. Failure to respond to the court's Order may result in the dismissal of the action.

Does it mean that the Order itself will not be submitted until the response is filed? Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if you want a definitive legal answer, you need to ask this at https://law.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The Order won’t be considered to be “submitted” until the response to the “Order to Show Cause” is filed.

Comment: There's no trick to understanding the sentence, as the components "the Order will stand submitted" and "upon the filing of the response" are readily comprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your assumption. One of the meanings of the word stand is "to be in a specified state or condition".  So the order will be in the state of having been submitted when the response is filed.